# Remove fields from Kibana dynamic mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, field, kibana

We have added some documents in the elasticsearch which had superfluent fields (a lot). The specific documents have been deleted, but the dynamic field mappings from kibana remain, even after recreating the index-pattern.

Is there any possiblity to drop the fields from kibana that do not longer exist in elasticsearch?

- Kibana version: 4.4.2
- Elasticsearch version: 2.2.0

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings in kibana, and press the refresh button, now you will get the up to date fields

Comment: This does not solve the issue, it's like recreating the index-pattern.